# SQL syntax highlighting bug in StackOverflow

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

StackOverflow engine treats backslash character `\` as an escape symbol for string literals.
But backslash is NOT an escape symbol in SQL.
So, simple statement `select '\' from dual` produces incorrect syntax highlighting.

[Example of real SQL code with wrong highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14784078/1847592)

Please fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow doesn't have a syntax highlighting engine; it uses [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

In order to change the current behaviour you can either [raise an issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list) or submit a fix yourself. Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter will then be automatically updated when the latest version of Prettify is pulled.

Having said that even with an explicit language hint (`<!-- language: lang-sql -->`) a `\` is normally not used as an escape, though it is not rendered as a string literal.

```sql
select '\'
```

To take a portion of your example (this is quite difficult to see on my screen) it's still almost working

```sql
select ('^(.*?)(<.*?>)$', '\'||pos), blah
```

It's only the addition of more single quotes that causes it to break

```sql
select ('^(.*?)(<.*?>)$', '\'||pos)
  'blah' blah
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanations about Google Prettify.  I have noticed that SQLFiddle has the same problem, probably because of the same reason.  Unfortunately, `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` did not solve syntax highlighting problem in my code.

Comment: The hint is automatically added to the source already @Egor as the question is tagged [tag:oracle].